# Dynamic Combo box issue

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

Hi I'm using a table which two columns namely instrument and method. On click of a button, I'll add a row with the combo box as an editor in each cell. Also, those combo box wil have the actionlistener. Like when I'm selecting instrument, method combo box list should be changed. I'm using only two combo box and I'm instantiating it every time when I add a row. My problem is whenever I add a new row, the existing rows combos are getting reloaded with the latest value. That means, the combo boxes are unique even though I'm instantiating it differently. What is the way to create the combo box dynamically which should have the values of its own. Posting my code below for your reference.

```
addItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            comboInstrument = new CeNComboBox();
            comboMethod = new CeNComboBox();
            TableColumn instrumentColumn = table.getColumn("Instrument Used");
            TableColumn methodColumn = table.getColumn("Method Title");
            comboInstrument.removeAllItems();
            listInstruments = analyticalUtil.getInstruments(listAnalysisSummaryPrefs);
            iterateInstruments = listInstruments.iterator();
            while(iterateInstruments.hasNext()){
                comboInstrument.addItem(iterateInstruments.next());
            }
            dtm.addRow(new Object[]{" "," "});
            comboInstrument.setEditable(true);
            instrumentColumn.setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor(comboInstrument));
            instrumentColumn.setCellRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer());
            comboMethod.setEditable(true);
            methodColumn.setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor(comboMethod));
            methodColumn.setCellRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer());

            comboInstrument.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent argEvent){
                    comboInstrumentActionPerformed();
                }
            });
            comboMethod.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent argEvent){
                    comboMethodActionPerformed();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

MyComboBoxEditor.java

```
public class MyComboBoxEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {



    public MyComboBoxEditor(JComboBox combobox) {
        super(combobox);
    }
}
```

I'm very new to Swing. Please help me out.

Adding some sample code with hardcoded values. If you run this you will understand my problem. Test in this way. 
     1. Select a value from first column, first row and select value from another column. 
     2. Do the same in second row and now check the second column of first row. All the values will be reloaded based on the selection made for the second row. 
This is the problem I'm facing. The below code copied and edited from the following link 
  [JComboBox Action listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539001/jcombobox-action-listener)

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JComboBox mainComboBox;
        private JComboBox subComboBox;
        private Hashtable<Object, Object> subItems = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();

        public Testing() {
            String[] items = {"","Select Item", "Color", "Shape", "Fruit", "Size"};
            mainComboBox = new JComboBox(items);
            mainComboBox.addActionListener(this);
            mainComboBox.addItemListener(this);
            mainComboBox.setEditable(true);
            //prevent action events from being fired when the up/down arrow keys are used
            //mainComboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
//          getContentPane().add(mainComboBox, BorderLayout.WEST);
            subComboBox = new JComboBox();//  Create sub combo box with multiple models
            subComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXX"); // JDK1.4
            subComboBox.addItemListener(this);
//          getContentPane().add(subComboBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            String[] subItems1 = {"Select Color", "Red", "Blue", "Green"};
            subItems.put(items[1], subItems1);
            String[] subItems2 = {"Select Shape", "Circle", "Square", "Triangle"};
            subItems.put(items[2], subItems2);
            String[] subItems3 = {"Select Fruit", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana"};
            subItems.put(items[3], subItems3);
            String[] subItems4 = {"Select Size", "Big", "Middle", "Small"};
            subItems.put(items[4], subItems4);
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Instrument Used","Method Title"},0);
            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            table.getColumn("Instrument Used").setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor(mainComboBox));
            table.getColumn("Instrument Used").setCellRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer());
            table.getColumn("Method Title").setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor(subComboBox));
            table.getColumn("Method Title").setCellRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer());
            model.addRow(new String[]{""});
            model.addRow(new String[]{""});
            getContentPane().add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String item = (String) mainComboBox.getSelectedItem();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Action Performed "+item);
            Object o = subItems.get(item);
            if (o == null) {
                subComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel());
            } else {
                subComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel((String[]) o));
            }
        }

        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                if (e.getSource() == mainComboBox) {
                    if (mainComboBox.getSelectedIndex() != 0) {
                        FirstDialog firstDialog = new FirstDialog(Testing.this,
                                mainComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(), "Please wait,  Searching for ..... ");
                    }
                } 
            }
        }

        private class FirstDialog extends JDialog {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            FirstDialog(final Frame parent, String winTitle, String msgString) {
                super(parent, winTitle);
                //setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(msgString);
                JButton bNext = new JButton("Stop Processes");
                add(myLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                add(bNext, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                bNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        setVisible(false);
                    }
                });
                javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        setVisible(false);
                    }
                });
                t.setRepeats(false);
                t.start();
                setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
                setSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
                setVisible(true);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new Testing();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for new code. It's very helpful.

I play with your examlpe and rewrite it to work with editor properly.

Pay attention to following parts:

1. Testing. I remove subComboBox, you don't need it here. I remove actionListener for mainComboBox.
2. MyComBobBoxEditor. I implement method `getTableCellEditorComponent()`. This is a main method in editor. In this method I check which instrument is selected in current row and prepare editor comboBox for the particular instrument.

This example not includes editable comboboxes yet. But I hope it will be helpful for you.

```
public class Testing extends JFrame implements ItemListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JComboBox mainComboBox;
        private Hashtable<Object, Object> subItems = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();

        public Testing() {
            String[] items = {"","Select Item", "Color", "Shape", "Fruit", "Size"};
            mainComboBox = new JComboBox(items);
            mainComboBox.addItemListener(this);
            mainComboBox.setEditable(true);
            String[] subItems1 = {"Select Color", "Red", "Blue", "Green"};
            subItems.put(items[2], subItems1);
            String[] subItems2 = {"Select Shape", "Circle", "Square", "Triangle"};
            subItems.put(items[3], subItems2);
            String[] subItems3 = {"Select Fruit", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana"};
            subItems.put(items[4], subItems3);
            String[] subItems4 = {"Select Size", "Big", "Middle", "Small"};
            subItems.put(items[5], subItems4);
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Instrument Used","Method Title"},0);
            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            table.getColumn("Instrument Used").setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(mainComboBox));
            //table.getColumn("Instrument Used").setCellRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer());
            table.getColumn("Method Title").setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor());
            //table.getColumn("Method Title").setCellRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer());
            model.addRow(new String[]{""});
            model.addRow(new String[]{""});
            getContentPane().add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

       public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                if (e.getSource() == mainComboBox) {
                    if (mainComboBox.getSelectedIndex() != 0) {
                        FirstDialog firstDialog = new FirstDialog(Testing.this,
                                mainComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(), "Please wait,  Searching for ..... ");
                    }
                } 
            }
        }

        private class FirstDialog extends JDialog {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            FirstDialog(final Frame parent, String winTitle, String msgString) {
                super(parent, winTitle);
                //setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(msgString);
                JButton bNext = new JButton("Stop Processes");
                add(myLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                add(bNext, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                bNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        setVisible(false);
                    }
                });
                javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        setVisible(false);
                    }
                });
                t.setRepeats(false);
                t.start();
                setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
                setSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
                setVisible(true);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new Testing();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    class MyComboBoxEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, ItemListener {

            private JComboBox editorComboBox;

            public MyComboBoxEditor() {
                editorComboBox = new JComboBox();
            editorComboBox.addItemListener(this);
            }

            public Object getCellEditorValue()
            {
                return editorComboBox.getSelectedItem();
            }

            public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,
                    Object value,
                    boolean isSelected,
                    int row,
                    int column)
            {
                // which instrument is selected?
                String instrument = (String) table.getValueAt(row, 0);
                String[] methods = (String[]) subItems.get(instrument);
                editorComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(methods));
                editorComboBox.setSelectedItem(value);
                return editorComboBox;
            }

        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            stopCellEditing();
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Which events are you meaning? `EditingStopped` and `editingCancelled` already implementing in `AbstractCellEditor`.

Comment: I looked on it. All what i find is fire `stopCellEditing` when comboBox changed its selected item. I agree, will be better if I add it to code.

Comment: Thanks.. It is working fine. Item state changed event for editor combo box is not getting triggered

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you means here "_Item state changed event for editor combo box is not getting triggered_". Do you need additional listener of editing method column stopped? If so add one more ItemListener to `editorComboBox`. Or add `CellEditorListener` to `MyComboBoxEditor` and add your code to its `editingStopped()` method.

Comment: Based on the method selected, I have to change another text area. So, for that I'm tryig to use itemstatechanged event to get the selected item of the editor combo box

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it.. I'm using like editor.editorComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(editor.editorComboBox.getSelectedItem()!=null)
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, editor.editorComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
    
   }
  });

Answer (score 3):

First, you doen't need call `setCellEditor()`, `setCellRenderer()` each time when you add a row. This method must be called once after creation of the table.

Second, you should not create combobox when you add row. Better way is create combobox in `MyComboBoxEditor.getCellEditorComponent()` method.

I suppose you problems cause is wrong implementation of `MyComboBoxEditor`. 
When you create a new row you replace existing `TableCellEditor` and existing combobox editors for all cells in table, not only for just adding.
`TableCellEditor` provide editor component for each cell on demand. It must prepare editor component for particulare cell and return it. But I suppose your `MyComboBoxEditor` return the same component to each cell.
Can you provide code of MyComboBoxEditor to make sure?

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601436/jcombobox-as-a-custom-tablecelleditor). I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: I tried. But still I'm getting the latest values loaded for the recent combo box. I'm new to swing. I dono all the stuffs. :-(

Comment: Ok. Try again. Let's specify some point in your app. 1. Is items set in `comboInstrument` the same for all rows? 2. Is items set in `comboMethod` depends only on selected instrument value?

Comment: Yes. You are rite. Based on the instrument selected, the methods will get loaded. Instrument and method is also editable. Like new instrument or method can also be added.

Comment: All right. Another question. If I add new instrument or method in some row, must it appears in comboboxes at other rows? Appear as possible value , not as selected? of course.

Comment: No, that is not required. Because, combo box values will be retrieved from the database for the instrument. So when he clicks save, the newly added instrument should appear in each row.